# NP chart using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

how i can generate NP chart using ggplot2?

I made simple Rscript which generates bar, point charts. I am supplying data by csv file. how many columns do i need to specify and in gplot functions what arguments do i need to pass?

I am very new to R, ggplots.

**EDIT** : 
[This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Np-chart) is what is meant by an NP chart.

Current code attempt:

```
#load library ggplot2 
library(ggplot2) 

#get arguments 
args <- commandArgs(TRUE) 
pdfname <- args[1] 
graphtype <- args[2] 
datafile <- args[3] 

#read csv file 
tasks <- read.csv(datafile , header = T) 
#name the pdf from passed arg 1 
pdf(pdfname) 

#main magic that generates the graph 
qplot(x,y, data=tasks, geom = graphtype) 
#clean up 
dev.off()
```

In .csv file there are 2 columns x,y i call this script by `Rscript cne.R 11_16.pdf "point" "data.csv"`.

---

Thanks you very much @mathematical.coffee this is what i need but
1> I am reading data from csv file which contains following data

this is my data 
Month,Rate
"Jan","37.50"
"Feb","32.94"
"Mar","25.00"
"Apr","33.33"
"May","33.08"
"Jun","29.09"
"Jul","12.00"
"Aug","10.00"
"Sep","6.00"
"Oct","23.00"
"Nov","9.00"
"Dec","14.00"

2> I want to display value on each plotting point. and also display value for UCL,Cl,LCL, and give different label to x and y.

Problem when i read data it is not in the same order as in csv file. how to fix it?

Comment: What have you tried/can you give a small reproducable example of what you currently do to create the chart? We can't advise you on what arguments to pass etc if we don't even know what form your data takes.

Comment: Might also help to define the term NP chart; I assume you mean this - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Np-chart.

Comment: Thanks for reply.

@mathematical.coffee : I made script which reads csv file and generates bar in pdf format. 
`
#load library ggplot2
library(ggplot2)

#get arguments
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
pdfname <- args[1]
graphtype <- args[2]
datafile <- args[3]

#read csv file
tasks <- read.csv(datafile , header = T)

#name the pdf from passed arg 1
pdf(pdfname)

#main magic that generates the graph
qplot(x,y, data=tasks, geom = graphtype)

#clean up
dev.off()`

in .csv file there are 2 columns x,y 
i call this script by `Rscript cne.R 11_16.pdf "freqpoly" "data.csv"`

Comment: @neilfws: yes this is NP chart. I want to generate this kind of graphs.

Comment: `#load library ggplot2
library(ggplot2)

#get arguments
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
pdfname <- args[1]
graphtype <- args[2]
datafile <- args[3]

#read csv file
tasks <- read.csv(datafile , header = T)

#name the pdf from passed arg 1
pdf(pdfname)


#main magic that generates the graph
qplot(x,y, data=tasks, geom = graphtype)

#clean up
dev.off()`

`Rscript cne.R 11_16.pdf "point" "data.csv"`

Comment: @HeenaAgheda, do you mean you just want a line chart of y vs x with dots at the points and horizontal lines at UCL, CL, and LCL (I'm going off the wikipedia picture here), where the dots are red if they're outside the `UCL` and `LCL` limits? Have you already calculated `UCL` and `LCL` and `CL`? If not, can you provide some code specifying how they can be calculated from your particular data?

Comment: yes i have UCL and LCL calculated. I have month in x and value in y. 
I also want to label value with dot. and connecting lines in between

Comment: how i can manipulate lable in x? I mean i am suppling numeric value from csv file but while plotting lines i want display jan-dec. here is [link](http://dev.eqstat.com.au/withlines.pdf)

if i add `tasks$x <- factor(tasks$x,labels = c("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"))` 

it is displaying labels but no lines [link](http://dev.eqstat.com.au/withoutlines.pdf)


I need lines as well as need to change label..

how to Plot lines with text?

Comment: I could do with `p <- p + scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12), labels=c("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"))
`

is there any better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You combine `ggplot(tasks,aes(x=x,y=y))` with `geom_line` and `geom_point` to get the lines connected by points.

If you additionally want the UCL/LCL/etc drawn you add in a `geom_hline` (horizontal line).
To add text to these lines you can use `geom_text`.

An example:

```
library(ggplot2)

# generate some data to use, say monthly up to a year from today.
n <- 12
tasks <- data.frame(
    x = seq(Sys.Date(),by="month",length=n),
    y = runif(n) )
CL  = median(tasks$y)       # substitue however you calculate CL here
LCL = quantile(tasks$y,.25) # substitue however you calculate LCL here
UCL = quantile(tasks$y,.75) # substitue however you calculate UCL here
limits = c(UCL,CL,LCL)
lbls   = c('UCL','CL','LCL')

p <- ggplot(tasks,aes(x=x,y=y)) +            # store x/y values
     geom_line() +                           # add line
     geom_point(aes(colour=(y>LCL&y<UCL))) + # add points, colour if outside limits
     opts(legend.position='none',            # remove legend for colours
          axis.text.x=theme_text(angle=90))  # rotate x axis labels

# Now add in the limits.
# horizontal lines + dashed for upper/lower and solid for the CL
p <- p + geom_hline(aes(yintercept=limits,linetype=lbls)) +            # draw lines
    geom_text(aes(y=limits,x=tasks$x[n],label=lbls,vjust=-0.2,cex=.8)) # draw text

# display
print(p)
```

which gives:

[image: an np-plot]